# Online meeting preparation tool

Tags: web-apps, communication

I'm looking for an online tool (preferably a web-app, which doesn't require any set up for all the participants) to prepare and sumup meetings.

The idea is we use Google Calendar to set up our meetings, but we need a tool other than a mail discussion to prepare them so we are actually effective once we get into the meeting.

Imagine a weekly meeting about an ongoing software development. I'd like a tool with which I could :

- Create a project and add users to it
- Create an entry every week in this project for the meeting
- Invite the appropriate people to join the entry (all of the project users or not)
- Have the people concerned by the meeting write down what they want before the meeting (work done, blocking elements, planing status, ...)
- Have an overview of all this once we are in the meeting
- Type a report during / after the meeting
- Send the report to the people who were in this meeting
- Have a history of all the past meetings

Does such a tool exist? Note that all this could be done by mailing everyone but it would require some extra work, and would eventually spam the attendees inboxes.

I'd like to use a hosted solution, but if the software is exactly what I'm looking for and needs to be installed on my server, I wouldn't mind